# Getting the XPath for cordova's config.xml

Tags: xml, cordova, xpath

With cordovas confix.xml, the default file is this.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>HelloCordova</name>
  <description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
  </description>
  <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
  </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Using [gulp-xml-editor](https://github.com/morou/gulp-xml-editor) I'm trying to create a plugin to edit the value of `name`, but no matter how I try, I can't get the right xpath to the element.

Options I've tried:

- `.//*[name]`
- `.//*/widgets:name`
- `//name`

To no success. Any idea what it is?

Comment: +1 very interested in that solution. I'm using crappy a "replace" with gulp from a config file (  gulp.src(['config.xml']).pipe(replace('project_name', config.project_name))  where project_name is <name>project_name</name>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The element `<name>` is in default namespace `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"`. Generally in xpath, to select element in namespace you'd need to register a prefix that points to the namespace uri and use that prefix in the xpath.

I don't know about `gulp-xml-editor`, but there seems a very close example in the GitHub page [you linked](https://github.com/morou/gulp-xml-editor), specifically the one commented "*edit XML document by using user specific object using a namespace*" :

```
/*
  edit XML document by using user specific object using a namespace
*/
gulp.src("./manifest.xml")
  .pipe(xeditor([
    {path: '//xmlns:name', text: 'new names'},
  ], 'http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest("./dest"));
```

Comment: Perfect, I'm realizing that what I missed was passing the namespace after the array. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Never knew how the XPath fetching actually worked.